# how to access node variables in region preprocess function?

Tags: theming, hooks

I have variable in the node preprocessor:

```
function theme_preprocess_node(&$vars , $hook) {
    $vars['default_product_price'] = $vars['elements']['product:commerce_price'][0]['#markup'];
}
```

Currently, the variable 'default_product_price' is not available in the region--sidebar-second.tpl.php file. How would i make this variable available in region template file or page template file? Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The template files for nodes and pages don't share any variable; that is true also for their preprocess and process functions.

Assuming we are talking of a node field implemented with the field API, then what follows applies:

- The page preprocess and process functions have access to `$variables['node']` which contains the node object, in the case the page is a node page

  ```
  function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (!empty($variables['node'])) {
      $node = $variables['node'];
      // …
    }
  }
  ```
- The function to access the content of a entity field is [field_get_items()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7), which returns its raw content
- The function to render a entity field is [field_view_value()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7)

The following code should work.

```
  function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (!empty($variables['node'])) {
      $output = '';
      $node = $variables['node'];
      $items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field name');
      foreach ($items as $item) {
        $field_output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field name', $item);
        $output .= render($field_output);
      }
      // Set $variables with the value you need.
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, `$variables['view_mode']` is passed only to the node preprocess/process functions; that value would be helpful to `field_view_value()`, as its last parameter is the view mode.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure in what I'm going to say, but maybe you can use the process hook instead of the preprocess, it should be available then.

Comment: It doesn't change: Node preprocess/process functions are going to be called before the ones for the page.