# how can i access a node variable inside of theme_preprocess_page function?

Tags: theming

I'm trying to access a node variable, the id of a taxonomy term but i have to do it at the page level in theme_prepocess_page function. i did it in preprocess node like this

```
$libStatus = $vars['field_feature_library_status']['und'][0]['tid'];
```

in preprocess_page i tried this:

```
$libStatus = $vars['node']['field_feature_library_status']['und'][0]['tid'];
```

but i get this error...  *Cannot use object of type stdClass as array in….*

can someone explain how i can access this node variable in theme_preprocess_page function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried [field_view_values()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_view_value/7) and [field_get_items()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7)

```
function mytheme_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
    if (!empty($variables['node'])) {
      $output = '';
      $node = $variables['node'];
      $items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field name');
      foreach ($items as $item) {
        $field_output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field name', $item);
        $output .= render($field_output);
      }
      // Set $variables with the value you need.
    }
  }
```

Explained in here [how to access node variables in region preprocess function?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/81952/how-to-access-node-variables-in-region-preprocess-function)

I think you should also be able to use entity_metadata_wrapper as follow

```
$node = $variables['node'];
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('node',$node); 
$libStatus = $wrapper->field_feature_library_status->value();
```

Comment: $field_output = field_view_value('node', $node, 'field name', $item);

Comment: but i see it if i do a var_dump($items);

Comment: correction, no error. sorry, had a typo.

Answer (score 0):

As reported in [node.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!node!node.tpl.php/7), the field field_feature_library_status is available as raw value as `$field_feature_library_status`,  in the preprocess/process functions.

> Field variables: for each field instance attached to the node a corresponding variable is defined; for example, `$node->body` becomes `$body`. When needing to access a field's raw values, developers/themers are strongly encouraged to use these variables. Otherwise they will have to explicitly specify the desired field language; for example, `$node->body['en']`, thus overriding any language negotiation rule that was previously applied.

Comment: ??? i don't understand

Comment: $field_feature_library_status, just says undefined variable when used in preprocess node